# Highstock not redraw immediately while dragging the navigator in mobile

Tags: mobile, charts, highcharts

I am using high stock to draw a stock chart, while moving the navigator, the chart should redraw and the setExtremes event should be triggered.

it works fine on the desktop browser, but in mobile, i found the chart is not re drawed immediately while dragging the navigator, util i let go, thus i can not get the date range while moving the navigator, that is not really good user experience.

Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior in mobile client seems the **adaptToUpdatedData** attribute is set to **false**